# .innerText of an element is not showing up

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks, contenteditable, innertext

I have a div that is `contenteditable` and grabbing the div using `useRef()`, which is a reactjs hook.

When I try to display the text inside the contenteditable div, the alert shows nothing but the log shows the text.

Is there something I am missing?

**this is just a snippet I created**

```
export default function Input() {
  const inputRef = useRef();
    
  const showText = () => {
    console.log("text: ", inputRef.current.innerText);
    alert("text: ", inputRef.current.innerText);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <div ref={inputRef} contentEditable="true" supressContentEditableWarning={true} /> 
      <button onClick={showText}>Show text</button>
    </>   
  )
}
```

It also does't work when I use it as a value inside an object eg.

```
const obj = {
  text: inputRef.current.innerText
}
```

I will be thankful if someone can help me understand what is going on here!!

**UPDATE**
just don't use alert to debug lol.

Comment: how about if you assign inputRef.current.innerText to a variable and then pass it to both alert and console.log?

Comment: does innertext return an object or just a string?  `console.log(inputRef.current.innerText)`

Comment: https://codepen.io/audetcameron/pen/XWgjWYo working pen.  Are you sure you are importing React, and {useRef} in your component?

Comment: @Cameron It returns a string. also, I am importing them as well. I just didn't put them here. I only included a snippet.

Comment: I linked a working pen above, does that help? (look at the console)

Answer (score 0):

[`window.alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) only takes a single parameter, so only the first string is shown. If you pass in too many arguments to a javascript function, the extra parameters will simply be ignored. This is different from [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console/log), which is a variadic function, meaning it will take any number of parameters and display all of them.

Try `alert("text: " + inputRef.current.innerText)` instead.

Comment: hmm, maybe it's just alert that's having a hard time displaying it because nonetheless, I should be able to grab the innerText right? 
I tried your way and I also did `alert(inputRef.current.innerText)` and it was empty :(

Comment: Yes. You should be able to access `innerText` again. It's just a string. I don't know any reason why it should not be displayed in the alert window if you pass it as the first argument (unless the div has no inner text). You can open the javascript browser and run `alert(document.body.innerText)`. Depending on the browser you are using, it might not show the full string, but I would expect that something will show. Anyway. I wouldn't be too worried about window.alert. For debugging, use console.log instead. For messages to the user, use react and show it on the page.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything stopping you from getting the innerText using DOM like this-

```
var innerText = document.getElementById('elementName').innerText
```

then passing the value to your reactJS?

Comment: I've been told to not go with that route using `document.` cuz it's not really a reactjs thing, since react can handle the DOM. idk if that makes sense.

Comment: DOM is much easier to use, and while it's a quick fix, it gets the job done with little to no major reprocussions for the jery rigging.